# Bash in Emacs + OSX not finding gems installed via terminal.app?

Tags: ruby, bash, macos, emacs, rubygems

I am running bash in emacs on osx and its pulling gems from a different place then terminal.app

in bash:

```
which gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

in terminal:

```
which gem
/opt/local/bin/gem
```

How do I change the bash to match terminals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing the `$PATH` is different in the emacs bash shell. You can check it out by running this command in each.

```
echo $PATH
```

This is the lookup path used to find commands. You need to include /opt/local/bin into this.

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Place that line inside of your `~/.bashrc` file and it should be picked up by bash when used in emacs (unless it is being run under a different user or something).

---

**Update:**

As Singletoned mentioned in the comments, Emacs will not load the `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` but the Terminal will. This file likely already contains this `PATH` definition causing the two to have a different behavior.

I recommend moving the PATH definition from `bash_profile` file into `bashrc`. However Terminal will not load `bashrc` if `bash_profile` exists.

The solution is to add this to `~/.bash_profile`.

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

You can then move everything else into `bashrc` which will be included into `bash_profile`.

Comment: Just to clarify this slightly, when Emacs starts a bash session it will run .bashrc, but not .profile or .bash_profile.  Terminal runs .bashrc and one of .profile or .bash_profile.  That's why you had different paths.